# How to get the position of a moving object continuosly in a html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, web

I created a moving object in my html page using Javascript and I am supposed to return the x and y coordinates everytime it moves in the block.How am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getBoundingClientRect() method for the relevant element.
Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDivId");
console.log(element.getBoundingClientRect());
```

It will give you coordinates of all of it's corners from the top left corner.
And add an window.setInterval() callback to sample it's location and do what ever logic you want when it is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use .offset() jQuery function to get the current coordinate of elements

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
       var a =  $("#divTestBox1").animate(
                {
                        "left" : "200px",
                        "top"  : "200px",
                },5000,function(event){

                    var x = $("#divTestBox1").offset().left;


                    var posx = $('#pos').html('left:'+x +'px');


                }
        );

});
</script>
<div id="divTestBox1" style="position: absolute;">rachana_sharma003</div>
<div id="pos"></div>
```